# Merge four indexed views in only one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 Express and Developer Edition with latest service pack.

I have created this three indexed views:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.RequestedCodesStatistics
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT CODE_LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_REQUESTED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    GROUP BY CODE_LEVEL
go

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Requested_Statistics ON dbo.RequestedCodesStatistics (CODE_LEVEL)
go
CREATE VIEW dbo.PrintedCodesStatistics
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_PRINTED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 1) OR
            (FLAG = 0) OR
            (FLAG = 20) OR
            (FLAG = 120)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
go

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Printed_Statistics ON dbo.PrintedCodesStatistics (LEVEL)
go

CREATE VIEW dbo.ReadCodesStatistics
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_READ
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 0) OR
            (FLAG = 20) OR
            (FLAG = 120)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
go

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Read_Statistics ON dbo.ReadCodesStatistics (LEVEL)
go

CREATE VIEW dbo.DroppedCodesStatistics
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_DROPPED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 11) OR
            (FLAG = 30) OR
            (FLAG = 31) OR
            (FLAG = 130)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
go

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Dropped_Statistics ON dbo.DroppedCodesStatistics (LEVEL)
go
```

As you can see, I'm only getting the statistics from `CODES` table depending on its `FLAG` column value.

How can I create one view with the five columns: `CODES_REQUESTED`, `LEVEL`, `CODES_PRINTED`, `CODES_READ` and `CODES_DROPPED`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "filtered aggregation trick":

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [CONDITION] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MyFilteredCount
```

Filter on any condition you like.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
With RequestedCodesStatistics as 
(   
    SELECT CODE_LEVEL Level, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_REQUESTED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    GROUP BY CODE_LEVEL
),
PrintedCodesStatistics as 
( 
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_PRINTED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 1) OR
            (FLAG = 0) OR
            (FLAG = 20) OR
            (FLAG = 120)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
),
ReadCodesStatistics as 
(
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_READ
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 0) OR
            (FLAG = 20) OR
            (FLAG = 120)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
),
DroppedCodesStatistics as 
(
    SELECT LEVEL, COUNT_BIG(*) as CODES_DROPPED
    FROM dbo.Codes
    WHERE   (FLAG = 11) OR
            (FLAG = 30) OR
            (FLAG = 31) OR
            (FLAG = 130)
    GROUP BY LEVEL
)
select  a.Level ,    CODES_REQUESTED,CODES_PRINTED, CODES_READ , CODES_DROPPED
  from RequestedCodesStatistics a 
  left join PrintedCodesStatistics b
    on a.level = b.level 
  left join ReadCodesStatistics c
    on a.level = c.level 
  left join DroppedCodesStatistics d
    on a.level = c.level
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use your current views as source:

```
select 
    coalesce(RCS.LEVEL, PCS.LEVEL, ...) as LEVEL,
    RCS.CODES_REQUESTED, PCS.CODES_PRINTED, ...
from 
    dbo.RequestedCodesStatistics RCS with(noexpand)
    full join dbo.PrintedCodesStatistics PCS with(noexpand) on PCS.LEVEL = RCS.LEVEL
    ...
```